# CHARINDEX (, PATINDEX, and LIKE) returning false positives in T-SQL function

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, charindex

I have a T-SQL function as listed below that needs to return a specific value when specific substrings are in the target string.

I've tried to research this, but I'm seeing inconsistencies in whether it is `CHARINDEX(string, searchstring)` (seems to be correct) or `CHARINDEX(searchstring, string)`, and have looked into the `LIKE` and `PATINDEX` alternatives.

All three methods have resulted in no matches in obvious cases (most likely I just did something wrong), or it works, but also gives false positives.

In the example below, case '1ST' and '10ST' both return as if both were found as if it was '1ST10ST'.

I'm sure it is some simple format I'm missing, if you could point out the error.

Answers for `LIKE`, `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX` are welcome.

Function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus
    (@intAttribute VARCHAR)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intRunningTotal int = 0;

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '1ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 1;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '2ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 2;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '3ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 3;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '4ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 4;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '5ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 5;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '6ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 6;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '7ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 7;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '8ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 8;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '9ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 9;
    END

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '10ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 10;
    END

    RETURN @intRunningTotal;
END
```

Current test statements (in case they're wrong somehow):

```
SELECT DISTINCT '1ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('1ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '2ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('2ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '3ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('3ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '4ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('4ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '5ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('5ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '6ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('6ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '7ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('7ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '8ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('8ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '9ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('9ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine

SELECT DISTINCT '10ST' AS Strength, dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('10ST') AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise you end up with a parameter with a length of ***1*** character - usually *not* what you want !

Comment: Debugging tip: change your function body to `RETURN (LEN(@intAttribute))` and you should see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the issue with not defining a parameter length, I would not be implementing logic like this - or a scalar UDF at all.

Although you don't show it, presumably since your function is testing for each case, you can pass a string with multiple qualifying values which you want to sum.

You should always try to write *table valued* functions which are orders of magnitude faster, especially when used with larger resultsets.

Based on what you have shown, try the following:

```
create or alter function SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus (@intAttribute varchar(50))
returns table
as
return (
    select [Value]=Sum(try_convert(int,value))
    from string_split(replace(@intAttribute, 'ST', ','), ',')
);
```

Use as you would any other table and *select* from it, *join* to it or *apply* it:

```
select [Value] from dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('10ST');
```

Result: **10**

```
select [value] from dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('1ST2ST3ST');
```

Result: **6**

```
SELECT DISTINCT '10ST' AS Strength, b.[value] AS StrengthBonus
FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
CROSS APPLY dbo.SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus('10ST')b;
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be useful going forward.  There are other codes to account for, but doing something along the lines of creating temp tables to match on would be at least more performant.

Comment: Yes if you can build a list that you can join on in a set-based fashion this will always be preferable to using a scalar function with iterative steps.

Answer (score 2):

Because your parameter length might be declared higher than your input string length otherwise it will be 1 as the default value.

Besides that, I would use `ELSE IF` instead of multiple `IF` in your case, because it can get better performance.

```
create or alter FUNCTION SDACalculateAttributeStaticBonus(
    @intAttribute VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intRunningTotal int = 0;

    IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '1ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 1;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '2ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 2;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '3ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 3;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '4ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 4;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '5ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 5;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '6ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 6;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '7ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 7;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '8ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 8;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '9ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 9;
    END

    ELSE IF( CHARINDEX(@intAttribute, '10ST') > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @intRunningTotal = @intRunningTotal + 10;
    END

    RETURN @intRunningTotal;
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably award you the answer when I can retest.  While you're correct it would be more performant, I think it needs to account for multiple instances of codes.